# Problem with querying using ST_GeometryFromText() postgis

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to get all places which is in radius of 100 km, but I'm getting error saying: **ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "01" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry**
I have a table:

```
     name     |                    geom                    
--------------+--------------------------------------------
 Kumpir Kebab | 01010000002C6519E25807354023DBF97E6A144A40
 Burger King  | 0101000000728A8EE4F2EF344076711B0DE0154A40
(2 rows)
```

And I'm using query:

```
SELECT * FROM place WHERE ST_Distance(
ST_Transform(ST_GeometryFromText(geom)',4326),2100),
ST_Transform(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(21.0287 52.1595)',4326),2100)
) / 100 >= 100;
```

Who can help?

[image: problem]

Answer (score 1):

The column named "geom" already contains geometries.  You cannot convert it from text a second time.